# "No tests found. Nothing was run" error in selenium automation using TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-annotation-test

Given below is the code that I coded using selenium in eclipse.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
class GoogleSearchTest {

    @Test
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\acer\\Downloads\\selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver =new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        WebElement we1 = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        we1.sendKeys("GMAIL");
        we1.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); 
        WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h3[text()='E-mail - Sign in - Google Accounts']"))).click();
        Thread.sleep(10000); 
        driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("2017cs102@stu.ucsc.cmb.ac.lk");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='identifierNext']/div/span/span")).click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("mmalsha425@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='passwordNext']/div/span/span")).click();

    }

}
```

It gives the following error.

```
[TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run
Usage: <main class> [options] The XML suite files to run
```

I have already installed TestNG plugin.What can I do to fix this problem??

Answer (score 0):

Change the main function name. You should not use it while using TestNG

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\acer\\Downloads\\selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver =new FirefoxDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write `main()` method, TestNg do that by itself.

```
class GoogleSearchTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException{
        //your code here
        .....
    }
}
```

If you want to call from `main()`, simply:

```
import org.testng.TestNG;

public class Master {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { GoogleSearchTest.class });
        testng.run();
    }
}
```

But note, in `GoogleSearchTest` class don't put **`public static void main`** for `@Test`

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
[TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run
Usage: <main class> [options] The XML suite files to run
```

...implies that the *TestNG* found no tests hence nothing was executed.

---

### TestNG

[TestNG](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) is an annotation-based test framework which needs a marker annotation type to indicate that a method is a test method, and should be run by the testing tool. Hence, while using [testng](/questions/tagged/testng) as you use [annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html) and you don't have to call the `main()` method explicitly.

---

### Solution

The simple solution would be to replace the `main()` method with a test method name e.g. *`test()`* and keep the `@Test` annotation as follows:

```
// your imports

class GoogleSearchTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\acer\\Downloads\\selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
        // other lines of code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reframing the method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
```

like this:

```
public void search()
{
    // -----your code----
}
```